# Type Object includes string?

Tags: typescript, typeguards

```
function isObject(v: any): v is Object{ 
    return v instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(v);
}


let v: string | Object;
if (isObject(v))
    v.hasOwnProperty("x");
else
if (typeof v === 'string')
    v.trim();             //Error: Property 'trim' does not exist on type 'never'
```

I am confused with that error in the last line, apparently, v gets narrowed to type 'never" but I can't see the logic of it.
(Typescript version 4.2.3)

Comment: At type position use `object` (not `Object`) https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgeQEYCsCm0AUAbgFyICGYAngJSmHIqJzZ5SIDeiAUIr4gE44oIfknowwKKBQg44wRJlzREAMlWIAhAEF+-MpQB0qXfspFqAbi4BfLlwAmeADZlBiZ0MQlEU-hIBzRAAfJhZoaxgFfFQlVgtqHj5CQwALMnQAdzAABX44AAccfihzACIADzKrLhxnFBwuKMR8UqL5b0QAXh7EAHI-QL7Evm9DKH8AW3wrIA

Comment: There is a lot of ways to improve this code. But I guess this error he is getting is because his if and else is wrong.  He doesn't need else in this case.

Comment: Why you need to include string and Object in a single variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how `Object` interface defined in typescript:

```
interface Object {
    constructor: Function;
    toString(): string;
    toLocaleString(): string;
    valueOf(): Object;
    hasOwnProperty(v: PropertyKey): boolean;
    isPrototypeOf(v: Object): boolean;
    propertyIsEnumerable(v: PropertyKey): boolean;
}
```

Almost any type including primitives like `string` is assignable to `Object` (yes string have all of the above properties).

[object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type) (lowercase) is a type that represents the non-primitive type, i.e. anything that is not `number`, `string`, `boolean`, `symbol`, `null`, or `undefined`

```
function isObject(v: any): v is object {
    return v instanceof Object && !Array.isArray(v);
}

declare let v: string | object;
if (isObject(v))
    v.hasOwnProperty("x");
else
    v.trim(); // v narrowed to string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgeQEYCsCm0AUAbgFyICGYAngJSmHIqJzZ5SIDeAUIj4gE44oIPknowwKKBQg44wRJlzREAMhWIAhAEE%20fMpQB0qHXspFqAbk4BfTpwAmeADZkBiJ4MQlEkvuIDmiAA%20TCzQVjDy%20KiKrObU3LyEBgAWZOgA7mAACnxwAA44fFBmAEQAHqWWnDhOKDiJPMlQfgC2%20JaIAPRdXohgrnkZOPaIUHA%20LQFAA)

[Do's and Don'ts](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types)

Answer (score 1):

```
let v: string | Object;
```

While executing the instanceOf(type checker) is considering v variable type as `string` because of you mentioned string as first type and Object is a second type of that variable. So in this case without having any value of that variable how the instanceOf know the type?. So it will check `null instanceof Object`. Which means null is not an object type. This is the reason to why `isObject()` return false. See

```js
console.log(null instanceof Object)
```

> If you assign any value, then only the instanceOf will be considered the type based on value because of that variable have **two** data types.

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation for this seemingly weird behaviour is that `object != Object`. Whereas object is a type that represents all non primitive types (not a string) the Object type is just an interface that contains common methods around javascript Objects like toString() etc.

In the function signature there is:

```js
v is Object
```

This will just check whether your variable type implements all methods of the `Object` interface. Actually for `string`, this is the case and therefore Typescript thinks:

Wait, he is providing me with a variable that is either `Object` or `string` and both of them implement the `Object` interface, thus the method will return true every time. Thats why it is `never` in the else case of the if.

If you use `object` instead of `Object` this will be fixed because `object` is a type that represents all non primitive types (not `string`). Therefore, typescript doesn't think that your function will return true all the time like with Object.

Answer (score 1):

```
const a: Object = '1'; // OK
const b: Object = 1; // OK
const c: Object = false; // OK
const d: Object = {}; // OK
const e: Object = undefined; // Error
const f: Object = null; // Error

const g: object = '1'; // Error
```

```
type T1 = string extends Object ? boolean : number; // boolean
type T2 = Number extends Object ? boolean : number; // boolean
...
type T3 = undefined extends Object ? boolean : number; // number
type T4 = null extends Object ? boolean : number; // number
```

That is to say, the `Object` is type of ONLY the members defined.
and every type extends Object except for undefined and null

SO

`v is Object` ===> `v is object`